# Uncaught TypeError - Fancybox & jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox, shopify

I'm using fancybox with [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin . My idea is to load the fancybox after page load and don't display it until next day. So I've the below code in place

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openNewsletterPopup() {
      setTimeout( function() {
        $('#newsletter').fancybox({maxWidth: 600});
        $('#newsletter').trigger('click'); 
      }, 
      {% if settings.newsletter_popup_seconds != blank %}{{ settings.newsletter_popup_seconds }}{% else %}2{% endif %}*1000);
    }

    $(function() {
      var popup = $.cookie('popup');
      var cookie_enabled = {% if settings.newsletter_popup_days != blank and settings.newsletter_popup_days != "0" %}true{% else %}false{% endif %};

      if (cookie_enabled && popup == 'open') {
          return false;
      } else {
        openNewsletterPopup();
      }
      if (cookie_enabled) {
        $.cookie('popup', 'open', { expires: {{ settings.newsletter_popup_days }} });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

But it's not working. I'm seeing Uncaught Type Error in my console. Any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Header code

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0815/3527/t/2/assets/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?2070714040394294891" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0815/3527/t/2/assets/jquery.cookie.js?2070714040394294891" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Have you included the required references to those plugins?

Comment: Yes i do. I've them included in my header jquery.js :)

Comment: Can you post the header code too?